# Is it possible to align Text or other drawn graphics to a feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, feature-class, graphics

I regularly have to input measurements such as 15' or drawn lines (not feature class lines, just a graphic) to building footprints that are polygon FC's.

Are there any tools to line up/align graphics to feature classes in Data View?

Comment: Are you really using ArcMap 10.1, which was retired two Januarys ago? Most of the folks here that use ArcGIS are using something modern, so you're not going to have a lot of overlap in terms of compatibility.

Comment: Why haven't the select and rotate tools on the drawing toolbar worked?